# How to get specific json data directly from URL

Tags: json, url

Hi,

I have an API URL like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://example.net&screenshot=true&key=someweirdkey
```

this takes me to a json page with a lot of data, but I only need what is here: lighthouseResult -> audits -> final-screenshot -> details -> data

is there anyway to retrieve that by inserting an specific URL? Such as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://example.net&screenshot=true&key=someweirdkey&query=lighthouseResult-audits-final-screenshot-details-data
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation, this is not possible.

See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed